# How do I see the remote device connected to my PC?

Tags: windows, connection, usb, device

I have an MT2070 scanner, and when I connect it to my PC using a USB cable, I can see all the files and folders on the scanner (I have ActiveScan installed). However, unlike when I connect a CD ROM drive, there is no letter association (its not the D drive or E drive, etc).

My goal here is to write a simple BAT file that copies a file from the PC to the device. But from a DOS prompt, I cannot manually copy a file to this device because I don't know what to call it. I don't know the proper syntax. It's not like a network drive either, because it doesn't have any IP address. When I open Windows Explorer, it is simply called "Mobile Device". Please advise, what is the simplest way to write a script to copy a file to this device?

Comment: Voting to close as this doesn't have anything to do with programming. Try posting on Super User instead.

Comment: Well actually it does have to do with programming. The file I want to update is my VB program on the MT2070 scanner. I had asked this question in a different format and received no response. And my device is not an Android App, so SuperUser is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

normally USB devices implement multiple functionalities (USB device classes) by multiple descriptors. A smartphone with tethering function i.e. implements *USB mass storage class* and *USB CDC class* (*RNDIS* device,...)  . normally you can switch between the interfaces using some commands on the device (on an android phone switch on the tethering).

In the User Guide on page 262 ff ( *https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/manuals/barcode-scanners/mt2000-mt2070-mt2090-user-guide-a-us.pdf* ) are listed the USB device classes that the MT2070 implements, this includes *USB CDC ACM* (Virtual COM port) and *HID class* (Human Interface Device). The virtual COM port is also a possible interface to the internal file system of the scanner. How USB interface switching works for the MT2070 is in the *User Guide* on page 265 ff

The USB interface of the scanner has to be configured, see User Guide page 146 ff on this.

The recommended way to access the internal file system of the  MT2070 over USB is to use *ActiveSync* (first the USB interface has to be configured). When the connection is established the VB programs like the `ScanItem` or `ScanInventory` can be modified , this is in the *UserGuide Quick Startup Exercise* on pages 473 - 478

complete explanation of the connecting process is on http://www.jmmsoftware.com/Documentation/MT2070/MT2070_Manual_rev_2011-11-02.pdf (includes *Mobile Device Center*)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538820(v=vs.85).aspx

---

If your device shows up as '*Mobile Device*' in Windows Explorer it is connected via MTP or a similar protocol ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol ). To copy files over MTP (or a similar protocol like i.e. PTP) by code you have to use the **Windows Portable Devices API**

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, including the page numbers. However, I am already using my MT2070 with a USB cable, and I am already using ActiveSync. But the descriptions you cited in the user guide tell only how to Manually move files onto the scanner. I can manually move the files. What I am looking to do is automate the process.